# Replace {{word}} in string

Tags: php, arrays, string, str-replace

Have a string: `$str = "Hello, {{first_name}} {{last_name}}!";`

And variables `$first, $last...` in **array**

```
$trans = array("{{first_name}}" => $first, "{{last_name}}" => $last, "{{cart}}" => $crt1, "{{phone}}" => $phone, "{{adds}}" => $addr, "{{order_id}}" => $order_id);
```

How to replace `{{first_name}}->$first`, `{{last_name}}->$last`

Here what i did:

```
function replace_str($str, $trans)
{
    $subj = strtr($str, $trans);
    return $subj;
}

$cart = replace_str($str,$trans);
```

But `strtr` doesn't work with **cyrillic (utf-8)**

Comment: I you can use the str_replace() function with array it's a native function : http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: ^ `return str_replace(array_keys($trans), $trans, $str);`

Comment: Did nothing help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **str_replace** with **array_keys**.

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
$str = "Hello, {{first_name}} {{last_name}}!";
$first = "ХѠЦЧШЩЪЪІ";
$last = "ЬѢꙖѤЮѪ";
$crt1 = "";
$phone = "";
$addr = "";
$order_id = "";
$trans = array("{{first_name}}" => $first, "{{last_name}}" => $last, "{{cart}}" => $crt1, "{{phone}}" => $phone, "{{adds}}" => $addr, "{{order_id}}" => $order_id);

echo str_replace(array_keys($trans), array_values($trans), $str);
```

Check the output at: https://3v4l.org/0fCv3

Refer:

1. http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php
2. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Comment: No need to ser `array_values` in second arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. [`strtr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) supports multibyte strings, but the array form `strtr(string, array)` should be used. Example:

```
$str = "Hello {{first_name}}!";
$first_name = "мир.";
$trans = ['{{first_name}}' => $first_name];
echo strtr($str, $trans); // Hello мир.!
```

Answer (score 0):

use str_replace(); , you can resolve your problem.

```
$str = "Hello, {{first_name}} {{last_name}}!";
$str1 = str_replace("{{first_name}}",$first,$str);
$str2 = str_replace("{{last_name}}",$last,$str1);
echo $str2;
```

First i have replaced {{first_name}} with $first in $str. Then I have replaces {{last_name}} with $last in $str1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) or [str_ireplace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) for case insensitive version.

Here example as your code,

```
str_replace(array_keys($trans), $trans, $str);
```